# Как у своей метки-изображения сделать кликабельной всю область?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Пытаюсь сделать кликабельной всю кастомную метку, но кликабельной остаётся только само содержимое. Если же делать смещение, тогда содержимое не будет по центру. На скрине https://skr.sh/s9ie2HAr7J6 кликабельная лишь жирная выделенная область.

```
let mark = new ymaps.Placemark(coords, { iconCaption, iconContent }, {
    openEmptyBalloon,
    iconImageSize: [37, 48],
    iconLayout: 'default#imageWithContent',
    iconImageHref: `/assets/images/placemarks/${color}.png`,
    iconContentLayout: ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
        '<div style="font-weight:bold;width:37px;height:48px;padding-bottom:14px;display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center">$[properties.iconContent]</div>'
    )
});
```

Comment: Вот этот пример не помог? https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_shape

Comment: пока не пробовал, а можно ли увеличить размер стандартного пресета?
а то у меня не влезает число =( https://skr.sh/s9iLT2xVyS2

Comment: Дефолтный макет менять нельзя, можно создать свой с помощью [фабрики макетов](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/templateLayoutFactory.html). За ширину и высоту отвечают опции placemark.style.width / placemark.style.height