# Почему при масштабировании метки смещаются?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Создал метки по вопросу [Как у своей метки-изображения сделать кликабельной всю область?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1321280/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%8e-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c).
При масштабировании они постоянно смещаются от их реальных координат. Видео, как это выглядит, можно увидеть по ссылке https://disk.yandex.ru/i/7m-7J2LedGEGXA.

Answer (score 0):

При добавлении на карту Яндекс меток с кастомным изображением следует корректно рассчитать [iconImageOffset](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Placemark.html#Placemark__param-options.iconOffset) - смещение левого верхнего угла иконки относительно её "ножки" (точки привязки).

Пример есть в песочнице Яндекс - https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/icon_customImage